# Gradle: how to copy subproject jar to another subproject when task is run?

Tags: java, gradle

I have the following multiproject structure in Gradle:

```
- root-project
  - acceptance-tests
  - sub-java-proj
```

`acceptance-tests` has a task `cucumber` (provided by Gradle Cucumber-plugin) which runs the Cucumber features in the project. However, I need to do some bootstrapping before the features are run. In particular, before the`cucumber` task Gradle should do the following:

1. Run tests in `sub-java-proj` and if they pass produce its jar file (if not fail)
2. Copy the jar file from 1) into the directory `accentance-tests/proglib`
3. Run the Cucumber features like normal
4. Delete the jar file copied in 2)

I'm completely new to Gradle so I am not sure how to properly implement this. My first thought was to make `acceptance-tests` depend on `sub-java-proj` (with testRuntime config), but I feel this is an abuse of the dependency mechanism: the only reason to do this is to ensure `sub-java-proj` is compiled before `acceptance-tests` is run, but in reality this also messes with the classpath of `acceptance-tests` by adding the jar from `sub-java-proj` and there's also problems with transitive dependencies. In short: `acceptance-tests` should not have *anything* to do with `sub-java-proj` besides copying it's jar around.

Suggestions on how to accomplish this are very much appreciated.

#### Update

So far I have the followingin `acceptance-tests/build.gradle`:

```
task fix(dependsOn: ':sub-java-proj:jar', type: Copy) {
    from tasks.getByPath(':sub-java-proj:jar')
    to 'proglib'
}

task unfix(type: Delete) {
    delete fix
}

cucumber.dependsOn fix
cucumber.finalizedBy unfix
```

However, this works except that unfix deletes the `proglib` directory too. It should only delete the jar file. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: If it needs to copy the Jar, it also needs to make sure that the Jar was created, so a `dependsOn` is likely warranted. (Often Gradle can infer the task dependency automatically.) For copying, see `Copy` in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html). For deleting, see `Delete` in the same reference. For the latter you should probably use `finalizedBy` (see [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html)).

Comment: Thanks. I have added a partial solution constructed from you advice to my post.

Comment: You'll have to use `delete pathToBeDeleted`.

Comment: And how would I go about retriving `pathToBeDeleted` from `fix`?

Comment: You can't get it from `fix`. You can get it from the Jar task, e.g. `tasks.getByPath(':sub-java-proj:jar').outputs.files`. (`delete tasks.getByPath(':sub-java-proj:jar')` might work as well.) A better solution would be not to reference the other project's Jar task directly, but to get the Jar via a project dependency (`configurations { fix }; dependencies { fix ":sub-java-proj" }` etc.), or to move the acceptance tests to `:sub-java-proj`.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser, doesn't your example delete the *original* output files of the `sub-java-proj:jar` process, and not the ones that have been copied?

Comment: Sorry for that. But you can compute the path to be deleted in a similar way (see `Copy` in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html)).