# Build jar and put in resources that are built into another jar with gradle

Tags: java, gradle

So I have two gradle projects: P1 and P2. P2 does not depend on P1 to build, however, during the build phase of P2, I want to build P1, add it to my resources folder and then add that folder to P2's jar.

I am still new to the whole gradle thing, so I am looking for an example build.gradle that would do something like this.

Thanks!

EDIT: It should be noted that P1 and P2 are both modules within the same project.

My project structure looks like this:

Root Project

```
Root Project
|
|__P1
|  |
|  |__build.grdale
|
|__P2
|  |
|  |__build.gradle
|
|__settings.gradle
```

My settings.gradle looks like this:

```
include 'P1', 'P2'
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up finding a similar question here: [Gradle: how to copy subproject jar to another subproject when task is run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885224/gradle-how-to-copy-subproject-jar-to-another-subproject-when-task-is-run?rq=1)

The build gradle should end up looking something like this:

```
task fix(dependsOn: ':P1:jar', type: Copy) {
    from tasks.getByPath(':P1:jar')
    into 'path/to/resources'
}

build.dependsOn fix
```